# CORS headers are completely redundant due to cookie rules

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, cors

I have posted a question before about CORS and it was closed as a duplicate because there is a question with a reply that contains two words of my question. I can accept that however I have some follow up questions about it.

From the comments in my previous questions I understood that CORS has one great advantage. If you send your request to a different origin (proxy forwarding your data to the real host) your browser will not send the cookies of the "real" host to the proxy since their domain (origin) is different.

I think that this is not a reason for CORS (restrictions) to exist. The fact that cookies are not sent to an origin they are not received from has nothing to do with same origin policy. The RFC 6265 does not mention CORS headers and is on its own safe with cross origin requests. CORS headers have no influence on how cookies are sent.

The fact that Bob (the real server) knows that a request is not from Alice (the real client) but from Peter (a transparent proxy) is because of cookies. However Alice is not sending the cookies of Bob to Peter not because of the CORS headers but because of the way cookies work (Peters domain does not match Bobs domain). In fact CORS only comes into play when Alice receives the response of her request, whether it is from Bob or Peter. Therefore allowing unrestricted access to cross origin resources would not taint that security in any way.

So my question boils down to:
Is there any real benefit of how annoying CORS was standardized versus just allowing anyone to access any resource from any origin and relying on cookie handling for authenticity?

Comment: CORS is really about javascript in the browser. Cookies can work without Javascript enabled. Cookies are about state persistance in the browser, CORS is about whether a network resource can be accessed by JS  or not.

Comment: But what is the benefit? If I have a transparent proxy that relays everything to a server adding an `Origin: *` header to the response and tricks the client to send its request to that server instead of the real server what do you win if you ignore the fact that cookies are not sent to a different origin?